# Python: Reading binary file into a structure and then unpacking

Tags: python, c++, endianness

I am converting a c++ code into python. C++ code reads a binary file and then converts it to a different endianness. I am facing problem doing the same in python. Can someone help me on the same?

Here is the C++ code:

```
  if( bByteSwap ) // make big-endian
  {
     pHdr = (UDUMPHDR *)buf;
     iAPID = pHdr->sHdr.ccsdsHdr.sW1.uAPID;
     iType = pHdr->sHdr.ccsdsHdr.sW7.uFmtID;
     iSeqCnt = pHdr->sHdr.ccsdsHdr.uiPktSeq;


     for( BYTE *pB=buf; pB<buf+nSz; pB+=2 ) ByteSwap( pB, 2 );
}
else    // already big-endian
{
    ::CopyMemory( buf1, buf, nSz1 ); 

    for( BYTE *pB=buf1; pB<buf1+nSz1; pB+=2 ) ByteSwap( pB, 2 );

    pHdr1 = (UDUMPHDR *)buf1;

    iAPID = pHdr1->sHdr.ccsdsHdr.sW1.uAPID;
    iType = pHdr1->sHdr.ccsdsHdr.sW7.uFmtID;
    iSeqCnt = pHdr1->sHdr.ccsdsHdr.uiPktSeq;
}
```

Here, `UDUMPHDR` is a structure. I am using ctypes in python to create same structure and using `fileHandle.readinto(s)` function to read the structure from the binary file. Can someone help me on what is the best way to do this?

Currently Written Python Code:

```
class UDUMPHDR(Union):
_fields_ = [("sHdr", TLEDUMPHDR),
            ("wHdr", WORD * int(sys.getsizeof(TLEDUMPHDR)/2)),
            ("bHdr", BYTE * sys.getsizeof(TLEDUMPHDR))]


hFile = open(myFile, 'rb')
s = UDUMPHDR()

print("Bytes read:", hFile.readinto(s))

#Make it Big Endian
if(bByteSwap):
    print("PktCnt:" + str(s.sHdr.pktHdr.uiPktCnt))
    iAPID = s.sHdr.ccsdsHdr.sW1.uAPID
    iType = s.sHdr.ccsdsHdr.sW7.uFmtID
    iSeqCnt = s.sHdr.ccsdsHdr.uiPktSeq

else:

    buf1 = copy.deepcopy(s)
    iAPID = buf1.sHdr.ccsdsHdr.sW1.uAPID
    iType = buf1.sHdr.ccsdsHdr.sW7.uFmtID
    iSeqCnt = buf1.sHdr.ccsdsHdr.uiPktSeq
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or Python 2? Are you familiar with the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module?

Comment: @PM2Ring I am using Python 3 and know about struct module. But I am not exactly sure how to use it. A little direction would be of great help. t

Comment: @PM2Ring I am using Python3 and know about `struct` but unfortunately I am not able to make use of it. A little direction would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you posted your current Python code, even if that's mostly just the ctypes structure definitions. (I may not be able to offer much help, since I don't know C++, although I do know C).

Comment: if you don't need to call any C api with this struct, then do not use ctypes, but parse it with the help of `struct` module.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I am finding it dificult to use `struct`. Can you please give me an example for the above?

Comment: This is only about reading the `TLEDUMPHDR` - what is the layout of `TLEDUMPHDR` itself? `struct` module can handle the byteswapping in itself, you do not need anything like described in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the code that you copied does is a very complicated way of byte-swapping `int16_t` values. The [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) module can readily handle it for you, so you do not need to worry about it.

The real problem there is to read the actual `TLEDUMPHDR` using its actual layout.
Say, you have a structure with the following layout:

```
typedef struct TLEDUMPHDR {
    int32_t x;
    int16_t y;
    int16_t z;
} TLEDUMPHDR;
```

and you are reading it from little-endian and writing it to big-endian. The [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) for that is `'ihh'`; and the flag for big-endian is `>`, and the little-endian is `<`; thus we get:

```
import struct

buf = bytes([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])  # 8 bytes

from_big_endian = struct.unpack('>ihh', buf)
to_little_endian = struct.pack('<ihh', *from_big_endian)
```

Comment: What if the above structure is a nested structure or has a union member in it?

Comment: It's helpful but still I am not able to resolve struct of structs or struct of unions.  :(